# Graphene resolver for an object that has no model

Tags: python, django, graphql

I'm trying to write a resolver that returns an object created by a function.  It gets the data from memcached, so there is no actual `model` I can tie it to.

I think my main issue is I can't figure out what `type` to use and how to set it up.  I'm using this in conjunction with Django, but I don't think it's a django issue (afaict).  Here's my code so far:

```
class TextLogErrorGraph(DjangoObjectType):

    def bug_suggestions_resolver(root, args, context, info):
        from treeherder.model import error_summary
        return error_summary.bug_suggestions_line(root)

    bug_suggestions = graphene.Field(TypeForAnObjectHere, resolver=bug_suggestions_resolver)
```

Notice I don't know what `type` or `field` to use.  Can someone help me?  :)

Answer (score 23):

GraphQL is designed to be backend agnostic, and Graphene is build to support various python backends like [Django](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/) and [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/sqlalchemy/en/latest/). To integrate your custom backend, simply define your models using Graphene's [type system](http://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/) and roll out your own resolvers.

```py
import graphene
import time

class TextLogEntry(graphene.ObjectType):

    log_id = graphene.Int()
    text = graphene.String()
    timestamp = graphene.Float()
    level = graphene.String()

def textlog_resolver(root, args, context, info):
    log_id = args.get('log_id') # 123
    # fetch object...
    return TextLogEntry(
        log_id=log_id,
        text='Hello World',
        timestamp=time.time(),
        level='debug'
    )

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):

    textlog_entry = graphene.Field(
        TextLogEntry,
        log_id=graphene.Argument(graphene.Int, required=True),
        resolver=textlog_resolver
    )


schema = graphene.Schema(
    query=Query
)
```

[image: Example query with GraphiQL]

Comment: That's a very good example even after 3 years, thanks