# Graphene resolver for nested custom object

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

I'm trying to use Graphene to model the following data: a `MessageFrequency` object, which represents the number of messages sent on a given date for a particular chat, and a `MessageFrequencyRange` object which represents the number of messages sent per day for a range of dates, all for a given chat.

I've tried creating custom classes and have been able to get the `MessageFrequency` object queryable by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45407521/6587177) stackoverflow post, but I'm confused on how to get a nested custom object working. Below is my current code.

```py
class MessageFrequency(graphene.ObjectType):

    chat_id   = graphene.Int()
    date      = graphene.Date()
    frequency = graphene.Int()


class MessageFrequencyRange(graphene.ObjectType):

    chat_id     = graphene.Int()
    start_date  = graphene.Date()
    end_date    = graphene.Date()
    frequencies = graphene.NonNull(graphene.List(graphene.NonNull(MessageFrequency)))

    def resolve_frequencies(self, info):
        return [
            # some method to instantiate a MessageFrequency object...
            # Query.resolve_message_frequency ?
        ]

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):

    message_frequency = graphene.Field(
        MessageFrequency,
        chat_id=graphene.Int(required=True),
        date=graphene.Date(required=True),
    )
    message_frequency_range = graphene.Field(
        MessageFrequencyRange,
        chat_id=graphene.Int(required=True),
    )

    def resolve_message_frequency(self, info, chat_id, date):
        # test data for now
        return MessageFrequency(
            chat_id=9000,
            date=date,
            frequency=1
        )

    def resolve_message_frequency_range(self, info):
        # Should be creating a MessageFrequencyRange object, but not sure how to fill
        # in the frequencies attribute which isn't a scalar
        return None
```

I'm not sure how I should be resolving the `MessageFrequencyRange` object inside `Query`, because it's more complicated than resolving a `MessageFrequency` object (as it has non scalar fields). I'm also not sure how to resolve the `frequencies` attribute of `MessageFrequencyRange`, I would think I should use the previously written resolver but I'm unsure on how exactly to call it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

I've done a nested object yesterday. I will try to answer. Would be good If you post your models.

```
 class MessageFrequencyType(DjangoObjectType):
     class Meta:
        model = MessageFrequency # Not sure about the name of your model


 class MessageFrequencyRangeType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
       model = MessageFrequencyRange # Not sure about the name of your model


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    message_frequency = graphene.List(MessageFrequencyType)
    message_frequency_range = graphene.List(MessageFrequencyRangeType)

    def resolve_message_frequency(self, info, **kwargs):
        return MessageFrequency.objects.all()

    def resolve_message_frequency_range(self, info, **kwargs):
        return MessageFrequencyRange.objects.all()


class CreateMessageFrequency(graphene.Mutation):
    chat_id = graphene.Int()
    date = graphene.Date()
    frequency = graphene.Int()

   class Arguments:
       chat_id = graphene.Int()
       date = graphene.Date()
       frequency = graphene.Int()

   def mutate(self, info, chat_id, date, frequency):
       message_frequency = MessageFrequency(
           chat_id=chat_id,
           date=date,
           frequency=frequency,
       )
       message_frequency.save()

   return CreateMessageFrequency(
       chat_id=message_frequency.chat_id,
       date=message_frequency.date,
       frequency=message_frequency.frequency
   )


class CreateMessageFrequencyRange(graphene.Mutation):
    chat_id = graphene.Int()
    start_date = graphene.Date()
    end_date = graphene.Date()
    frequencies = graphene.Field(MessageFrequencyType)

   class Arguments:
       chat_id = graphene.Int()
       start_date = graphene.Date()
       end_date = graphene.Date()
       frequencies = graphene.Int()

   def mutate(self, info, chat_id, start_date, end_date, frequencies):
       chat_id=chat_id
       start_date=start_date
       end_date=end_date
       frequencies = MessageFrequency.objects.filter(id=frequencies).first()
       if not frequencies:
          raise Exception('Message Frequency not found')

   MessageFrequencyRange.objects.create(
       chat_id=chat_id,
       start_date=start_date,
       end_date=end_date,
       frequencies=frequencies
   )

   return CreateMessageFrequencyRange(
       chat_id=chat_id,
       start_date=start_date,
       end_date=end_date,
       frequencies=frequencies
   )


class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    create_message_frequency = CreateMessageFrequency.Field()
    create_message_frequency_range = CreateMessageFrequencyRange.Field()
```

Comment: I'm trying to make this without using the Django or Flask+SqlAlchemy bindings, so I don't have any models. Would something like this s till work without using Django?

Comment: Not sure about that.