# How to get current instance of model in graphene-python DjangoObjectType

Tags: python, django, graphene-python

I have a **graphene-python DjangoObjectType** class, and I want to add a custom type, but I don't know how to get the current model instance in the resolver function. I am following [this tutorial](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/objecttypes/), but I can't find any reference.

This is my **DjangoObjectTypeClass**:

```
class ReservationComponentType(DjangoObjectType):
    component_str = graphene.String()

    class Meta:
        model = ReservationComponent

    def resolve_component_str(self, info):
        # How can I get the current ReservationComponent instance here?. I guess it is somewehere in 'info', 
        # but documentation says nothing about it

        current_reservation_component = info.get('reservation_component')
        component = current_reservation_component.get_component()

        return component.name
```

My question is different from [Graphene resolver for an object that has no model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312252/graphene-resolver-for-an-object-that-has-no-model), because my object DOES HAVE A MODEL. I don't know why it was marked as "possible duplicated" with such an evident difference. My question is, indeed, based on the model.

Comment: @PetarP no, it is not a duplicated question because my object DOES HAVE A MODEL, and my question is indeed based on such model. The question you are referencing has noting to do with the problem I am trying to solve

Comment: ops, sorry, didn't read it properly, will remove it.

Comment: Hey, here, there is good example in the [docs](http://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/interfaces/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is somewhere in `info`, namely here:

```py
type_model = info.parent_type.graphene_type._meta.model
```

But if you use `DjangoObjectType`, then instance is passed to `self`. So you may go another way:

```py
class ReservationComponentType(DjangoObjectType):
    component_str = graphene.String()

    class Meta:
        model = ReservationComponent

    def resolve_component_str(self, info):
        # self is already an instance of type's model (not sure if it is in all cases):
        component_class = self.__class__

        current_reservation_component = info.get('reservation_component')
        component = current_reservation_component.get_component()

        return component.name
```